# How to find the variables defined in a function

Tags: javascript, variables, function, introspection

Suppose I have a long javascript function such as

```
function test() {
    var x; 
    var a;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

is there any way I can ask the function itself to tell me what variables were defined so far.

```
function test() {
   var x; 
   var a;
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ... // bit of code that would say to me: x and a. 
}
```

Comment: Just curious, where do you need this ? Thanks

Comment: The javascript code is autogenerated. If I knew the answer of my question I would be able to add up at the end of a function a bit of code which would validate some assumptions made by the code generator.

Comment: I *wish* this was possible. Oh I so wish.

Comment: Do you need to know all defined variables or just whether a specific one is defined? The latter **can** be done, the first AFAIK not.

Comment: @Adrian: I don't think it can, you can't get at the execution context's variable object to do the `in` operation, and if you check the name to see if its value is `undefined`, that doesn't differentiate between no `var` at all vs. having the `var` but it having the value `undefined` (because you never assigned to it, or at some point assigned `undefined` explicitly). If it's possible, I'd love to know how, that'd be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without relying on `Function#toString` and then performing string processing on the result, which is not recommend. `Function#toString` is implemented by most browsers as giving you the source code of the function (with or without comments, depending), but isn't standardized by the spec (even the latest) and I wouldn't use it in production code.

Comment: Agreed I would not want to rely on the .toString
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

That would require reflection. But Javascript comes without very much any reflection support. I don't think you can do it, except like this: parse your own function.